Equality check is failing even though the numbers are the same. The first number keeps checking in as less than the second number
I am trying to compare two numbers.
I can't seem to figure out why the first number is always returning as not equal to the second number. I tried parsing it with Math.round() before comparing them but the first number keeps matching as less than the second number.

Formatted code:


'use client'

import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

interface ScrollProviderProps {
    onIntersect: (entry: IntersectionObserverEntry, direction: 'up' | 'down') => void;
}

export default function ScrollProvide({
    onIntersect,
}: ScrollProviderProps) {

    // const [scrollDirection, setScrollDirection] = useState<'up' | 'down'>('up')
    const scrollDirectionRef = useRef<'up' | 'down'>('up')
    const lastYPositionRef = useRef(0)

    const observerInstanceRef = useRef<IntersectionObserver | null>(null)
    const scrollContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)

    function intersectionHandler(entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[], observer: IntersectionObserver) {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {

            // Checks if the entry just left the screen from the top. We will the category to this
            // This means that we are scrolling down and the title just left the screen so we are going to update the title context to this
            if (entry?.rootBounds?.top && (entry.boundingClientRect.top < entry?.rootBounds?.top)) {
                console.log('bounds update down', {
                    'entry.top': entry.intersectionRect.top,
                    'root.top': entry.rootBounds?.top,
                    'bool': entry.boundingClientRect.top == entry?.rootBounds?.top,
                })

                onIntersect(entry, scrollDirectionRef.current)
            }


        })
    }

    const updateScrollDirection = () => {

        if (window && scrollContainerRef.current) {

            let currentScrollDirection: typeof scrollDirectionRef.current = 'up'

            if (scrollContainerRef.current.scrollTop > lastYPositionRef.current) {
                currentScrollDirection = 'down'
            } else {
                currentScrollDirection = 'up'
            }
            
            scrollDirectionRef.current = currentScrollDirection
            lastYPositionRef.current = scrollContainerRef.current.scrollTop
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (window && document.readyState === 'complete') {
            if (!observerInstanceRef.current) {
                const scrollMap = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=scroll-item-]')
                const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('#scroll-container')

                scrollContainerRef.current = scrollContainer as HTMLDivElement

                const options = {
                    root: scrollContainer,
                    rootMargin: "0px",
                    threshold: 0,
                };

                observerInstanceRef.current = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionHandler, options)
                scrollMap.forEach((element) => {
                    observerInstanceRef.current?.observe(element)
                })

            }


        }
    }, [window, document])

    return null

}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>




what does entry.intersectionRect.top have to do with entry.boundingClientRect.top - you "store" the former (as "entry.top") and compare the latter

Please post formatted code, not images of code.

Updated with formatted code requested.
Right now, I'm using a workaround that basically checks for the scroll direction instead of comparing the numbers. I'm still perplexed by the comparison.

I am using an IntersectionObserver here. Don't wish to store entry.top because I am just doing a comparison of the numbers as they intersect and then call the onIntersect handler.

"Equality check is failing even though the numbers are the same. ": you display false for their equality. What are you on about when you say they are the same? They are not.

That is what I'm wondering here @trincot. The bool property is doing an equality check for entry.intersectionRect.top and entry.boundingClientRect.top. I outputted both values and they are both 65 and yet the equality check is still failing.

Those are not the pair you compared

I see it now thanks haha, I was too deep in the code.
